# How to zoom to a CGRect area in UIScrollView maintaining an aspect fit with the screen?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, aspect-ratio

I want to zoom in a particular rectangular area of an image inside `UIScrollView` and that rectangular area should **aspect fit** (*i.e. it always maintains its aspect ratio while touching the screen bounds and remains in the center of the screen*) on the device's screen. So depending on the rectangle, I have to change the size of my `UIScrollView` so that only that part of the image gets shown on the screen. The problem is that the `CGRect` values that I pass to `zoomToRect` aren't zooming in the image, only the image position and the size of the `UIScrollView` are changing. Here is the code:

```
if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - zoomWidth) / 2, (self.view.bounds.size.height - zoomHeight) / 2, zoomWidth, zoomHeight);
        [self.myScrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, zoomWidth, zoomHeight) animated:NO];
    }];
}
```

I have to change the size of my `UIScrollView` like shown in the image below so that only the desired zoomed rectangular part [gray part in the image below] gets shown on the screen.

[image]

Comment: Have you implemented *- viewForZoomingInScrollView:* ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It returns the `ImageView` that I want to zoom into.